# Scilab: get uninstanciated parameter of a function

Tags: function, scilab

I wanted to know if there exist a way to achieve someting like

```
-->80923=myCoolFunction(p,56,7)

    p=24
```

in Scilab? Here is the current result when I type this:

```
-->8761.7635 = tauxcompose(p, 4, 25)
Warning: obsolete use of '=' instead of '=='.
        !       


                       !--error 4 
Undefined variable: p
```

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what behavior you're looking for.
Do you want to know what p given to myCoolFunction results in 80923? Do you have a Matlab / GNU Octave example where this works? I've never seen such a thing.

Comment: Yes I want to know it there is a way to get the value of p if I call my function in such a way? Neither did I see such thing in Scilab, but I have an assignment where I need to calculate this p, and it is written that I don't need any computations or new functions to to it, so...

Comment: I've never seen such a thing in any programming language. Usually your inputs are defined on the right-hand side and outputs left. Without any functional knowledge about your problem, you could brute-force it and in a while loop keep trying values for `p` while the answer does not equal 80923.

Comment: I could work in Prolog maybe, but I don't even want to try it ahaha. I am probably go brute force as you said. Thanks for answering :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use `fsolve`, as documented @ https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.1.0/en_US/fsolve.html

**Example:**

```
function r = myCoolFunction(p,a)
    r = p .^2 .* exp(-a*p)
endfunction
```

`p` is the variable. `a` is an extra parameter (like in your example a=56, etc).

Now we search for p such that for instance `myCoolFunction(p,1) == 100`, assuming that there is at least one solution. We build

```
deff("out = gap(p,a,c)","out = myCoolFunction(p,a) - c")
```

Initial guess p0 : Display the plot of `myCoolFunction(p,1)` and see where it is around 100

```
p0 = -3;
```

Then we call `fsolve`:

```
[p,v,status] = fsolve(p0, list(gap,1,100))
```

*Result:*

```
-->    [p,v,status] = fsolve(p0, list(gap,1,100))
 p  = 
  -2.6534493

 v  = 
   0.         means: the found solution p is exact (up to the default relative tolerance 1e-10)

 status  = 
   1.         means: fsolve() has well converged to a solution
```

*Independent checking:*

```
--> myCoolFunction(p,1)
 ans  =
   100.
```

Now, **what is `p` to get `myCoolFunction(p, 2) == 1e4`** ?

```
p = fsolve(-4, list(gap, 2, 1e4))
myCoolFunction(p, 2)
```

Result and checking:

```
--> p = fsolve(-4, list(gap, 2, 1e4))
 p  = 
  -3.3856301

--> myCoolFunction(p, 2)
 ans  =
   10000.000
```